# QWaitCondtion not waking

Tags: c++, qt5, mqtt

I am trying to wait for a single message to be received over MQTT.

I subscribe to a topic which gets called back in the MQTT client thread.
I want to wait for 1second and abort the wait if the message has not been recieved.

If I debug I can see the callback get called and it block on the mutex until the wait condition releases it. But I never wake from the wait condition.

```cpp
    QMutex read_mutex;
    QWaitCondition wc;
    // install callback for async read
    callback = [&read_mutex, &wc](MQTTAsync_message* msg) {
        read_mutex.lock();
        printf("got message");
        //release the wait on message read
        wc.wakeAll();
    };

    read_mutex.lock();
    mqtt_client.register("mytopic", callback);
    mqtt_client.subscribe("mytopic", 1);
    // wait on message read
    if (!wc.wait(&read_mutex,1000)) {
        printf("Failed to wait for message");       
    } else {
        printf("waited for message");
    }
    read_mutex.unlock();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `wc.wait`, you are holding `read_mutex`.  Within the callback, you call `read_mutex.lock()` again before you `wc.wakeAll`, so `wc.wait` never wakes up from, and your code is deadlocked.

Your code also uses variables that are not defined in scope.  I guessed at their type.  having two different mutexes called `wait_read` and `read_mutex` is a strange choice, however.  Did you intend them to be the same mutex?

Comment: The two variable names is the product of cleaning up the code snippet to post.    The lock inside the call back is there to ensure that the wakeAll happens after the WaitCondition releases the mutex in wait.  How else can I ensure that happens?

Comment: @techn Provide a [mcve].  This means you reduce the code to minimal code that actually reproduces the problem.  You minimized, but clearly did not reproduce the problem with the minimized code, because you used variables that did not exist in the minimized code.

Comment: fair enough - was trying to avoid having to write a stripped down version of my MQTT library